# how to read datagridview data in windows forms coulmn wise in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi Can any one suggest how to read data from datagrid in windowsforms application which has two columns(FileName and FilePath).
Below is the code I tried its returning all Filename and FilePath in single column(FileName).
Any suggestions would be helpful to me..

```
 `
    public System.Data.DataTable ExportToExcel()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));

        for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
        {
            for (int col= 0; col < dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
            {
              table.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the line…

```
table.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
```

is only adding to the FIRST column. You are adding a new row for EACH column.

To add a row to a table that has two columns would be of the form…

```
table.Rows.Add(column1Value, column2Value);
```

Since you know there are TWO columns, simply loop through the rows. It is not necessary to loop through the columns.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));

for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++) {
  if (!dataGridView1.Rows[rows].IsNewRow &&
       dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value != null &&
       dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value != null) {
     table.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    }
  }
```

If it is unknown how many columns are in the `DataGridView` and you must loop through the columns… then you will need to make sure there are at least as many columns in the `DataGridView` as there are columns in the `DataTable`.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));
DataRow newRow;
if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count >= table.Columns.Count) {
  for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++) {
    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[row].IsNewRow) {
      newRow = table.NewRow();
      for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++) {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null)
          newRow[col] = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
        else
          newRow[col] = "";
      }
      table.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what object `dataGridView1.DataSource` is, just visit the object. It would be much easier.

Besides, there's a simple way to export data from DataGridView to Excel:

1. `Ctrl+A` Select all cells in DataGridView.
2. `Ctrl+C` Copy them.
3. `Ctrl+V` Paste them in a sheet of Excel.